# How can I access Custom Metadata objects without having to hard code in Apex?

Tags: apex, metadata, custom-metadata

I hope you all agree that hard coding object names is not scalable or maintainable. I would like to lookup the field based on a string input received from the user. Is there any way to do this using Apex?

I know the following code shows how to create a Custom Metadata field but how do I access it using Apex after creating it?

```java
Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
customMetadata.fullName = 'ISVNamespace__MetadataTypeName.MetadataRecordName';

Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
customField.field = 'customField__c';
customField.value = 'New value';

customMetadata.values.add(customField);
```

An example code below as shown on Custom Metadata Type Methods help page by Salesforce hard codes Custom Metadata field (Games__mdt) which I don't believe is a good practice. Am I wrong?

```java
List<Games__mdt> mcs = Games__mdt.getAll().values();
boolean textField = null;
if (mcs[0].GameType__c == 'PC') {
   textField = true;
}
system.assertEquals(textField, true);
```

I am also puzzled why `$CustomMetadata.YourCustomMetadataFieldName__mdt` is an acceptable way to access Custom Metadata field in a validation rule but `$CustomMetadata` is not acceptable in Apex.

Comment: Thank you Kris!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I hope you all agree that hard coding object names is not scalable or maintainable

I don't agree. I think it is relatively unusual for this to be the case. Most code does directly reference the types with which it interacts; in fact, this is in some ways a *positive* pattern as it allows the Apex compiler to validate your code at compile time.

> I know the following code shows how to create a Custom Metadata field but how do I access it using Apex after creating it?

That is not what this code does. It is preparing (but not deploying) a *record* of a Custom Metadata type that already exists, and populating an existing field on that type with a value. Check out the [Apex reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_namespace_Metadata.htm) for more on what this namespace does, or complete the [Apex Metadata API](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_metadata_api) module on Trailhead.

You can interact with Custom Metadata records data dynamically the same way you can with regular sObjects, including Dynamic SOQL and methods like `get()`.

Performing schema changes, like creating a new field on an object, dynamically is generally not a good idea and is a good solution pattern for a very, very limited set of use cases.

> I am also puzzled why $CustomMetadata.YourCustomMetadataFieldName__mdt is an acceptable way to access Custom Metadata field in a validation rule but $CustomMetadata is not acceptable in Apex.

The formula language and Apex are completely different.